# Subversion reverting resolved file

Tags: svn, merge, branch, revert

If I was to make an error in a file that I have marked resolved is there a way to go back to having the file in it's original conflicted state without reverting all changes and reattempting the merge?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there is no automatic way to do that. If you want to be able to do that, you'll have to manually back up the .mine file ahead of time so that you can get it back if needed.

Comment: I've created a utility Svn Conflicts Backup to backup and restore conflicts so you can resolve them again. http://www.donationcoder.com/forum/index.php?topic=29885