# undo a 'resolve' without revert and remerge

Tags: svn, merge, revert, resolve

I'm doing a merge. After merging I commit all files without conflicts. Then  I resolve single files and commit them. If I make a mistake how do I redo the resolving (even if I haven't committed the resolved file yet)?

Contrary to expectation I cannot revert the file. When reverting back to any step after the merge none of the files become conflicted again. This means I have one chance to resolve correctly or having to revert the wc to a point before the merge and reattempt the merge - which takes a long time.

It seems when doing a merge the act of merging is applied as a property on the working copy root folder, and then the wc is considered merged, whether or not there are conflicts outstanding. Is it right that  none of the conflicts are marked as such in the repository?

Deleting the file and doing an `svn update` did not succeed as I retrieve the file as if it wasn't merged and attempting to merge again does not find any changesets.

Comment: Just found this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5381263/subversion-reverting-resolved-file

Answer (score 2):

revert does what it should do -- revert the file to the version without any edits from you. Therefore there aren't any conflicts, because anything you modified is reverted. Resolving should create temporary files with your and "their" version, on which diff works. You should take your version and remove the other one, so you can update and try to resolve again. Backing up the file to resolve is what you need to do if your svn does not create these temporary files!